# Are there benefits of using oAuth for your own service if you don't intend to share it?

Tags: web-services, authentication, oauth, authorization

I have a REST API that will be accessed from mobile clients and a web application. I would like to use oAuth for it. Not necessarily for the resource sharing aspects (it will just be for our application right now) but because of the standard it provides for how to tokenize and sign requests.

My questions:

- Is this a sane use of oAuth?
- There are quite a few posts on here discussing the issue of having to
  store the client secrets on the mobile devices, but is that really an
  issue in this case since I own the service too?
- Is there any reason to give each client their own secret? This is normally used for access revoking, but again, I control the serivce and could just disable their user account.